Can a Force spirit travel through time?
When one becomes a Force ghost it is said that they become more powerful than possibly imagined. We’ve seen Force ghosts in both Canon and Legends appear anywhere (including other galaxies), in Canon they can interact with some physical objects such as Luke using the Force to catch his lightsaber and hold it in his hand. Yoda was able to summon a lighting bolt from the sky to destroy the tree full of Jedi texts with just a finger twitch. In Legends, Obi-Wan once possessed Luke to help him fight Vader. With all that power, could they travel backwards in time? There is a power called Flow walking from Legends that lets you do that when you are alive (yet you can’t alter the past); and in Canon, the ghosts of Ben and Anakin and Yoda could see that Luke had much darkness in the future but opted not to burden him with that in that moment.
Could they travel backwards in time if they wanted?
